# Soundflower + AU Lab Mojave?

Tags: soundflower

I had an AU Lab preset saved from before updating to Mojave that used to work on macOS High Sierra.

It seems that the combination doesn't seem to work any more on Mojave. I'm not seeing any response in AU Lab at all.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The only reliable way this would work is to manually edit the TCC trust database:

```
sudo sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "insert into access VALUES('kTCCServiceMicrophone','com.apple.audio.aulab',0,1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UNUSED',NULL,0,1541440109) ;"
```

Comment: This was the answer which worked for me. The “just download it again” answer didn’t work—tccd would always say “Platform binary prompting is 'Deny' because: is Platform Binary”. Note that you don’t seem to need to use `sudo` for this command, but you do need to make sure that AU Lab isn’t running.

Comment: This would require SIP to be turned off, right?

Comment: I think no, this file is only for your own user, not the system.

Comment: I am on Mojave and got error when trying the above command: `Error: unable to open database "/Users/lacek/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db": unable to open database file`. If I try to copy the file: `cp -a ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db` throws `Operation not permitted`. Then I figured out that I have to grant my terminal app with `Full Disk Access` permission in under `Privacy` section of `Security & Privacy`. And I suggest to replace the hard coded timestamp (`1541440109`) with `CAST(strftime('%s', 'now') AS INTEGER)` to use current time.

Answer (score 3):

I found this thread on Apple's Support Communities: [AU Lab Not working on MacOS Mojave](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8552731) .

There's an answer that states:

> Update: I was able to make Au Lab show permission request, finally. I think the reason it didn't ask permission before was that it was somehow cached since I had Au Lab in my /Applications before updating to Mojave.
>
> It did request permission when I downloaded new version from [iTunes - Mastered for iTunes - Apple (CA)](https://www.apple.com/ca/itunes/mastered-for-itunes/), unzipped it right in my Downloads folder and launched it from there,  without moving to /Applications folder. That's when it said it's an app downloaded from the internet are you sure bla bla and then when I created document it asked for permission.
>
> After that you can delete Au Lab copy from Downloads and continue launching from /Applications — it'll work.

Downloading it and replacing it with the new one from Apple also worked for me.

Comment: You just beat me to it - similar thread on Soundflower GitHub - https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original/issues/86

Answer (score 2):

(Note that some people have problems with Soundflower on Apple Silicon; [Blackhole](https://existential.audio/blackhole/) ([github](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole)) is considered a decent replacement.)

On a **M1** MacBook Pro with **macOS Monterey 12.3**, here's what worked for me.

1. Grant Terminal.app Full Disk Access permissions. (Note that permissions changes while the app is running won't take effect until the app is restarted.)
2. In a Terminal window, paste this:

```bash
sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db \
    "insert into access VALUES(      
        'kTCCServiceMicrophone', 'com.apple.audio.aulab',
        0, 2, 0, 1, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, 'UNUSED', NULL, 
        0, $(date +%s) );"
```

(SQL purists could replace the `$(date)` shell interpolation with `CAST(strftime('%s', 'now') AS INTEGER`)

I basically used the same code [Lazek](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/59280/lacek) proposed but it was missing a value right after *'com.apple.audio.aulab'* so I took the values from [other post](https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/heroes/t/imac-os-big-sur-cannot-give-hots-mic-permissions/46219/9) which used *0,2,0,1* and voilá. AU Lab then appeared in the Microphone Permissions List and once I checked it, it worked like a charm.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing AU Lab, and redownloading not triggered Mic Permission on MacOS monterey.

Doing sudo command in one of answers gives following error.

`Error: table access has 13 columns but 12 values were supplied`

I passed extra 0 value and the entry appears as Disabled for "Security & Privacy" >> Microphone. Hope this will help some people.

```
sudo sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "insert into access VALUES('kTCCServiceMicrophone','com.apple.audio.aulab',0,0,1,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,'UNUSED',NULL,0,1541440109);"
```

Comment: Also the permissions not appearing is happening in some Apps, not just for Microphone, like Kernel error in VirtualBox VM opening. 

For that, it could be solved by using beta/testing builds of the app or need to contact the respective app developers.